# Calling ErrorProvider.Dispose does not clear the error text every time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application and am calling `ErrorProvider.Dispose` to clear the error text. However, when I call it a second time it does not work (i.e. if a textbox is empty the `ErrorProvider` will show but after I filled the textbox and pressed the submit button again, it won't show the error).

I have a form with many textboxes and Im just checking if the fields are empty or not after clicking the submit button:

```
foreach (Control c in this.college.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
        if (textBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
            {
                errorProvider1.SetError(textBox, "Field Empty");
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is only to clear the previous error message then simply call again the SetError method but pass in an empty string.

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text)) 
{ 
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox, "Field Empty"); 
} 
else 
{ 
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox, string.Empty); 
}
```

There is no need to call Dispose(). Rather, calling Dispose will destroy the errorprovider and it will be unusable for the rest of the lifetime of your form.

Comment: You should call `Clear` rather.

Comment: @leppie, no, Clear() will clear the settings of the error provider. But it depends on the real intention of the OP.

Comment: Thank you mr. Maarten, I figured it out too. but now when I put the errorprovider1.dispose the other textboxes succeding the filled texboxes has no errorprovider displaying.  I like mr. Steve's answer but I really want to make the errorprovider go away. not just stay there but not actually saying errors

Comment: if you remove the errorprovider with Dispose() then, when you need it again, you need to create from scratch with `errorProvider1 = new ErrorProvider();`. You can look at how the Visual Studio creates the first errorProvider1 inside the InitializeComponents() method located in the form.designer.cs file. In my opinion all the work required will be only error prone and don't gives you any special advantage

Answer (score 0):

I would think that your code never reaches the line with

```
errorProvider1.Dispose()
```

since the if-statement

```
if (textBox.Text.Equals(string.Empty))
```

make the second if-statement

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
```

useless.

If textBox.Text is empty, then it is also null-or-whitespace.

Comment: Thank you mr. Maarten, I figured it out too. but now when I put the errorprovider1.dispose the other textboxes succeding the filled texboxes has no errorprovider displaying.  I like mr. Steve's answer but I really want to make the errorprovider go away. not just stay

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to call .Dispose() on the error provider - this will be automatically collected by the garbage collection. Your code should probably look like the following:

```
   foreach (Control c in this.college.Controls)
    {

        if (c is TextBox)
        {

            TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;


             if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
             {
                errorProvider1.SetError(textBox, "Field Empty");
             }
             else
             {
                errorProvider1.SetError(textBox, "");
             }
        }
    }
```